# How can I block a user on my website from going to Rails_admin panel URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

How can I block Rails_admin panel URL and redirect user to home page when he tries to access it through URL? Can I do this from routes.rb?

I just installed Rails_admin gem and added route in routes.rb file.
Can I make conditions in routes.rb file to not allow access to user but only to admin? 
This is my route to Rails_admin 
`mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their [docs describe](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Authorization) this use case:

> Authorization can be added using the authorize_with method. If you pass a block it will be triggered through a before_action on every action in Rails Admin.

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with do
    redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.is_admin?
  end
end
```

This is set up in *config/initializers/rails_admin.rb*

**Further Explanation**

As mentioned in the docs, this triggers a `before_action` call with the passed block before *every* RailsAdmin action. You can imagine it like this

```
before_action :authorize_admin

def authorize_admin
  redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.is_admin?
end
```

It is similar to adding a `before_action` trigger to your ApplicationController - just that it automatically only triggers with RailsAdmin actions.

Comment: I would raise a 404 error instead of a redirect, because you are confirming the existence of the resource to a potential attacker.

Comment: Guillermo Siliceo Trueba, that is quite right. But how can we redirect this URL even when the user is not logged in?

Comment: the code is [taken from their docs](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Authorization) - please do adjust it to your use case. @JesseJames - you can just add `current_user.present?` to the if/unless statement

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in your appication_controller.rb file and you're good to go.

```
 RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with do 
    if current_user.nil?
      redirect_to main_app.root_path
    else
      redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.admin?
    end
  end
 end
```

This will redirect the page when user is not logged in or user is public.